# Google Sheet - Formula to split out dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dashboard that I'm creating, And it contains start and end dates, which I want to split out into months (which I'll group together later in order to create charts etc)

I'm not sure if this is possible but if I data like this (simplified for query purpose):
[image]

And I basically want to split the data like this:

[image]

I can achieve this with a script that I've written which the user can run by clicking a button. I was just curious if it's possible to achieve this using formulas (I'm fine with writing scripts, but still struggle with query and array formulas) since this is for a dashboard, I thought it would be nicer if the data updated "live" instead of having to click a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"×"&IFERROR(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(B2:B), 
 MONTH(B2:B)-1+IF(""=SPLIT(REPT(12, DATEDIF(EOMONTH(B2:B, -1), EOMONTH(C2:C, -1)+1, 
 "M")+1), 2), "♀",COLUMN(1:1)), 1), "mmm yyyy")))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"), {"@", "mmm yyyy"}))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a go and deconstruct it to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant answer but it does the work done by modifying an answer [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets/)

#### Formula:

```
=arrayformula(SPLIT(A4&";"&unique(text(sequence(days(C4,B4)+1,1,B4), "MMM YYYY")), ";"))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I have 3 cells with formula here (`E2` for Project A, `E9` for Project B and `E13` for Project C).
- You will need to change `A2`, `B2`, and `C2` to their respective cells for every entry.
- Regarding the manual clicking of a button on your script, I do recommend that you use `onEdit` trigger with your script instead to automatically trigger the script once a certain cell is edited (or a certain condition is met). That way, no buttons will be needed to be clicked.